# Should I use Redux store.subscribe() or wrap my app with react-redux <Provider>?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have seen the two approaches :
in [this example](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/SBhVBL15qx2vaMf1?preview), which is taken from a course by Dan Abramov,
he is using this approach :

```
const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter
      value={store.getState()}
      onIncrement={() =>
        store.dispatch({
          type: 'INCREMENT'           
        })            
      }
      onDecrement={() =>
        store.dispatch({
          type: 'DECREMENT'           
        })            
      }
    />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};

store.subscribe(render);
```

The store.subscribe() function in Redux allows to add listeners that get called when an action is dispatch.

in this [other example](https://redux.js.org/basics/exampletodolist), which is an example from Redux documentation :

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

the store.subscribe is not used, but instead they wrap the entire App inside a `<Provider>` component.

What’s the difference between the two approaches ?
It seems they are doing the same thing, which is to make sure the App has the last version of the state.

Can/Should I use Store.subscribe if i have wrapped my app with a `<Provider>` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **can** use the first method maybe but then you should pass the store every other component in the future. Doing this manually is a lot of work, but other than that it makes things hard, like testing, etc.

`Provider` is not a part of `Redux` but comes with `react-redux` to make the things easier. You wrap your component with it and it passes the store all the way down. `react-redux` also provides the `connect` function. You use it in the components wherever you want to reach your action dispatchers and your state.

So, you can easily see that using the `Provider` component is almost a de facto standard. So, probably you want to use it and do not bother with manually doing `store.subscribe` and passing your store to other components. So, if you use `Provider` you won't use `store.subscribe`.

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Then, in another component where you want to use the goodies of redux:

```
const Component = ...

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    value: state.someValueFromState
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { action, otherAction };

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
  // or you can use action creators directly instead of mapDispatchToProps
  // { action, otherAction }
)(Component);
```

Then, you can use your action creators and state values as props in the `Component`.

Answer (score 1):

The `<Provider>` component is specific to the official React-Redux binders. So if your'e using React-Redux (and not only Redux) use `<Provider>`. The `<Provider>` component will make sure that everything that's wrapped in it will have access to the store.

Answer (score 1):

In a real application, you shouldn't be subscribing to the store directly.  React-Redux does that for you.

Please see our new docs page on ["Why Use React-Redux?"](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/why-use-react-redux) for some further explanation, as well as my recent post [Idiomatic Redux: The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/) for details on some of the work that React-Redux does so that you don't have to.